# Deleting directory - Test file busy error

Tags: python

I have some code that is trying to delete a directory called `job_lists` at the location: `/home/vagrant/project/data.out`.  This directory contains a number of files.  The code that I am trying to use to remove the directory and its contents is as follows:

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def joblistMain(args):
    folder = '/home/vagrant/project/data.out'
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, 'job_lists')
    if os.path.isdir(folder):                    
        filepath = os.path.join(folder, 'job_lists')            
        shutil.rmtree(filepath)
```

However I get 'Text file busy' error:

```
[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/vagrant/project/data.out'
```

`data.out` is a folder. I am not running any other processes so am unsure as to why I am getting this error.  The error seems to be around the line `shutil.rmtree(filepath)` as I don't think while executing the code its past this line. How can I stop this happening and delete the directory?

Comment: So, is `data.out` a directory or a file?

Comment: How can `os.path.isdir('job_lists')` succeed? Are you running with `data.out` as your working directory? Perhaps that's stopping it being deleted.

Comment: What is the *full* traceback? Ideally, a (recursive) directory listing of `/home/vagrant/project` would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It seems `data.out` and job_lists are under the same parent directory i.e.

```
vikrant
-- project
-- -- data.out
-- -- job_lists
```

Making above assumptions, below is the code:

```
def joblistMain(args):
    folder = '/home/vagrant/project/data.out'
    if os.path.isdir(folder):
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(folder), 'job_lists')
        shutil.rmtree(filepath)
```

Comment: code only answers are likely to get downvoted, please explain what you're doing...

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your suggested solution @Ratnesh updated my question with updated code.  I am however still having the same issue.  for information data.out is a folder